# gente como que eu posso instalar o homebrew na minha maquina windowns 7?

Tags: homebrew

então aqui segue o link do site para quem puder ajudar está verificando o site, e logo após aqui quando eu abro meu prompt de comando me aparece o C:/users/Station>
dai por diante eu copio o código que está dentro do homebrew e color no prompt de comando para executar e ele diz a mensagem que, o arquivo na foi encontrado na pasta direcionada, alguém aqui poderia me ajudar como conseguir instalar o homebrew aqui segue o link do site da homebrew

homebrew site: https://brew.sh/index_pt-br.html

Answer (score 0):

então acabei de descobrir que o homebrew ele não funciona no windows apenas para o mc desde então se alguém tem duvidas em relação a isso aqui já está uma resposta para o seu problema se for parecido com esse que eu obtive ..